# SSH Server with Wordpress

Tags: ftp, ssh

I am connection my ftp with SSH protocol.
Wordpress ask for my ftp credentials. But even if i fill them correctly, it gives me an error saying wrong username/password.

my host is 93.94.254.231
and port is 3446

so i am writing  93.94.254.231:3446

do i need anything else?

Thank you

Comment: You might need to setup your configuration to be able to do this, see: codex entry [Editing wp-config.php](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php) sections [WordPress Upgrade Constants](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_Upgrade_Constants) and [Enabling SSH Upgrade Access](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Enabling_SSH_Upgrade_Access).

Comment: I assume you have the FTPS button clicked? Does your FTP server support this protocol?

Answer (score 4):

I don´t have the reputation for a comment, so an answer must do it.

1. WordPress uses (s?)FTP to install updates and plugins. Your SSH credentials are something different and most possibly not those ones of an FTP account.
2. If you want to use the built-in FTP function of WordPress your hostname is normally "localhost" because you want to install something on the same server. Port numbers are not used here.